TqdmCallback writes loss as loss=tf.Tensor(, shape=(), dtype=float32)
I have written a VAE model in Keras following this example.
The code is working as expected, however, the loss is being printed as
loss=tf.Tensor(, shape=(), dtype=float32). As seen in the picture.

Is that an issue with the custom model or the TqdmCallback?

There is no "TqdmCallback" anywhere in the code you linked.

Can you maybe post a snippet of your code? What you are seeing is simply tqdm printing the values retrieved directly from TensorFlow, which are of type tf.Tensor and not of the Python float primitive, and that is why you are getting that string. There is nothing wrong with it a priori, it should just be an aesthetical issue. You can probably fix it to make it nicer to look at, but it will not affect your training performance.
